# Extract just what is needed from params[:form]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Users can send a reply to feedback they received. Here is the form:

```
    <%= form_for :feedback, :url => reply_feedback_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :reply, :size => '66x7' %><br>
        <%= f.submit "Reply"  %>
    <% end %>
```

Here is the controller:

```
@reply = params[:feedback]
UserMailer.reply2_comments(@to_whom, @from_whom, @reply).deliver
```

If someone types in 'yo' into the text box, what is passed to the mailer is ' {"reply"=>"yo"} '

I'm having trouble with the syntax to extract just the content that was typed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing a hash to the mailer, and you just want the value for the key "reply".  So try:

```
@reply = params[:feedback] || {}
UserMailer.reply2_comments(@to_whom, @from_whom, @reply['reply']).deliver
```

The main thing I changed here was changing `@reply` to `@reply['reply']` in the mailer call

(I also added a nil-check to the first line to make sure @reply['reply'] won't cause an error if they don't submit the form by normal means)